# How to tell (at runtime) if a library was linked using cocoapods or not?

Tags: ios, runtime, cocoapods

I know this probably is impossible, but is there any footprint left by cocoapods that can point out (at runtime) if a library was installed using cocoapods or not?

I am currently able to find out if CocoaPods was used or not by getting the list of classes names and then looking for a class with the `PodsDummy_Pods_` prefix. But I have no way of knowing if a given library was or not linked using CocoaPods.

**Edit**

As clarification: I have access to the library source code, but I have no control over the final project. The library is distributed as a binary (static library), and we would like to know if the users installed it using CocoaPods or not.

Comment: is this question from a binary? or from a project?
What i mean to ask is that, you want to find out if any Cocoapods library was used at all.. right? from where do you want to find it out? from an IPA file or from the project itself?

Comment: It´s a binary (static) library, and I have access to that library source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to automatically detect this, so we solved it doing this: We added a custom `resource_bundle` in the Podfile, and then we just check if it's there or not on runtime, if it's there we are sure that the library was installed using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this mainly depends on whether you have control of the library.

If you don't, no not really. Those `PodsDummy-` classes exist at a target level, so they just indicate that CocoaPods *has been used*. However, it won't tell you if a specific library used CocoaPods.

For source code libraries, CocoaPods can add additional build flags which can expose additional APIs or strings which you can lookup in the same way. There is already a `"COCOAPODS"` build flag added, so it could use that.

For a binary library, it's possible but a bit tricky. In theory: you could  add a symbol to the lib/framework that can be discovered in the runtime, then in the Podspec's `prepare_command` that could be removed. I don't know what command would do that, but maybe `ar`, `strip` or `lipo`.

Comment: I have control over the library, and the Pod provides a binary file, so only the third option applies here, which is a great idea, but the library is a static framework, this means only the symbols that are actually being used will be copied in the final build, so this dummy symbol won't be there on release mode...

Comment: Now... we can refer this symbol in code, but only if the symbol is there, maybe this will fool the compiler to always include it.

Comment: I will give you the bounty to you, just because is the best idea I've seen so far. But I won't give you the ticket yet.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution is to place all Pods libraries into separate bundle. You project may have several bundles. As result you can ask in runtime Bundle(for: type(of: self)) in Swift or 
[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] in ObjC

Comment: I have control over the library, but not over the final project so I have no way to enforce this.

Comment: In case idea of some preliminary registration of classes is acceptable for your case there are 2 possible solutions which allow to run some registration code after image of your library was loaded into memory
1. Usage of principal classes for framework and its load method
2. usage of C function with __attribute constructor in separate file of your library
__attribute__((constructor(0))) void __loadMe() {
// here you can place code which will be executed as soon as your library will be loaded by the app
}

Comment: I understand this, but if you have a copy of the same library in two different applications, one that used cocoapods to install it, and one that didn't, how can you differentiate between the two using this?

Comment: as far as I know Cocoa pods specification allows to assign specific compilation flags for library
you can try to assign custom .compiler_flags -DCOCOAPODS
then you can use in in sources to separate  2 branches in code.
Next possible way is to play with .source_files list and add some specific file for installation via cocoa pods

Comment: But the compilation flags only exist on compilation time, and the library is already compiled, so it won't make any difference.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, CocoaPods includes particular Pod into project as source code and create from all Pods single framework. And this big framework will be complied as subproject of main project. The main project which includes the Pods framework and linked with it. In case your assign custom compilation flag for one of Pod this pod will be compiled and included into final framework according to your settings.

Comment: This is only true for Pods that provides source code (that are the most common). There's also Pods that includes an already built library (as a binary file), and this is our case.